# Adding role to a user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, role

I have this codes which work when adding a new account by using an admin account:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Owner")]
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(UserProfile userprofile)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.UserProfiles.Add(userprofile);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(userprofile);
}
```

but when I add this line of code

```
Roles.AddUserToRole(userprofile.UserId.ToString(), "4");
```

I get an error of:

> No user found was found that has the name "11".

What should I do? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the answer and it was just pretty simple. Firstly, you need to call your database and just add the following codes:

```
  webpages_UsersInRoles s = new webpages_UsersInRoles();
  var userid = WebSecurity.GetUserId(model.UserName);
  s.RoleId = roles;
  s.UserId = userid;
  db2.webpages_UsersInRoles.Add(s);
  db2.SaveChanges();
```

These are the codes that I lack in the problem above. Thanks to those who helped!

Answer (score 1):

You should use `UserName` not `UserId`, [check MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.security.roles.addusertorole(v=vs.110).aspx) on this method:

```
public static void AddUserToRole(
    string username,
    string roleName
)
```

Notise `username`? Also could be that you should use `roleName` not `RoleId`.

Comment: But it is connected to the webpages_UsersInRoles

Comment: and where do you adding this line then? i mean after SaveChanges method?

Comment: Yup. Actually, I have tried adding the line before and after the SaveChanges method but to no avail.

Comment: How to I convert the string parameters of the `AddUserToRole` method to int?

Comment: why do you need to convert them?